# Unexpected end of input. Что же там не так?

Tags: node.js

```
var fs = require("fs");
var util = require('util');
var EOL = require('os').EOL;

function Log() {
    // Nothing
}

module.exports = Log;

Log.prototype.setup = function(gameServer) {
    if (!fs.existsSync('./logs')) {
        // Make log folder
        fs.mkdir = function()  {
    // Nothing
}

    switch (gameServer.config.serverLogLevel) {
        case 2:
            ip_log = fs.createWriteStream('./logs/ip.log', {flags : 'w'});

            // Override
            this.onConnect = function(ip) {
                ip_log.write("["+this.formatTime()+"] Connect: " + ip + EOL);
            };

            this.onDisconnect = function(ip) {
                ip_log.write("["+this.formatTime()+"] Disconnect: " + ip + EOL);
            };
        case 1:
            console_log = fs.createWriteStream('./logs/console.log', {flags : 'w'});

            console.log = function(d) { //
                console_log.write(util.format(d) + EOL);
                process.stdout.write(util.format(d) + EOL);
            };

            //
            this.onCommand = function(command) {
                console_log.write(">" + command + EOL);
            };
        case 0:
            // Prevent crashes
            process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
                console.log(err.stack);
            });
        default:
            break;
    }
};

Log.prototype.onConnect = function(ip) {
    // Nothing
};

Log.prototype.onDisconnect = function(ip) {
    // Nothing
};

Log.prototype.onCommand = function(command) {
    // Nothing
}

Log.prototype.formatTime = function() {
    var date = new Date();

    var hour = date.getHours();
    hour = (hour < 10 ? "0" : "") + hour;

    var min  = date.getMinutes();
    min = (min < 10 ? "0" : "") + min;

    return hour + ":" + min;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Не хватает одной закрывающей фигурной скобки.

```
    if (!fs.existsSync('./logs')) {
        // Make log folder
        fs.mkdir = function()  {
    // Nothing
}
```